# Do I need my own docker image for CodeBuild environment?

Tags: docker, aws-codebuild

I have a few AWS lambdas written in Go and I'm using [serverless framework](https://serverless.com/) to deploy it.

Basically, I need nodejs + npm for serverless + Go runtime to build the project.

When I'm creating an AWS CodeBuild project I can choose the environment from the list (nodejs, Go, java, ...) or select a custom docker image.

What is the right wait to create the environment? Creating custom docker image is the only option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in aws codebuild it provide managed images like ubuntu and windows images.
and you can use your own docker images

i would prefer and suggest to use custom docker images with configuration. in default manage ubuntu image there will be no node and go.

so if you will use custom docker image thn you can manage own preferable version of node and go inside the docker image

Answer (score 1):

If your stack isn't in the configuration of CodeBuild. Create your container locally and registry in Amazon Elastic Container Registry. For me is the best way to work with CodeBuild configuration for containers.